# how to get auto increment and decrement value of check box after submitting in flutter

Tags: flutter, checkbox

Hi i am trying to display the check box value in the top of the page after submit the checkboxes.[image]

here if the gold value of one check box is 2 if we select 2 check boxes and submit it will show 4.

new CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(key),
                  value: values[key],
                  activeColor: Colors.teal,
                  checkColor: Colors.white,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      values[key] = value;

```
                  if(value) {
                    _incrementCounter(2);
                  } else {
                    _incrementCounter(-2);
                  }


                });
              },
            );
          }).toList(),

  _incrementCounter(int gold_value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int counter = (prefs.getInt('score') ?? 0) + gold_value;
    print('currenct score $counter ');
    await prefs.setInt('score', counter);
  }
```

Comment: i didn't understood your question ! But as of what I understood , If the user checks a box under gold then the points will be 2x right?? and silver 1x and platinum 3x ! Is it ???

Comment: yes exactly . i was already tried by using shared prefrences

Comment: Is it tabbed view ? Posting your code will be more helpful to get the best answer !

Comment: Does the checkboxlisttile layout is a single layout for all 3 categories or has separate layouts ??

Comment: All check boxes were in separate layouts

Comment: Then you can easily save the required points. I'm not getting what problem you are facing ?

Comment: Its better to share your complete code in that page/screen !